# Using interface/type in nuxt, how can I add getters to it?

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am using useFetch in nuxt to receive data. Now I put this into an interface or type, both work:

in my store:

```
        await useFetch(url, {
          onResponse({ response }) {
            const clients = response._data.clients as Client[];
            useClientStore().$patch((state) => {
              state.records = clients as Client[];
            })
          },
        });
```

interfaces.ts

```
  interface Client {
    id: number | null
    name: string
    status: string
    color: string
  }

  // OR
  type Client = {
    id: number | null
    name: string
    status: string
    color: string
  }
```

I am missing a chance to add a getter so I can basically calculate the color on the fly based on the status of the record. Any tips how I can do this are greatly appreciated. I searched all over the place how to add either to a type or interface but with no result.